# How to fill into this element?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to fill into this element using playwright python. The element is in an iframe and the number at the end of the tag is always different.
My code looks like this:

```
frame = page.frame_locator('.js-iframe')
await asyncio.sleep(3)
code = frame.get_by_placeholder('3 digits')
await code.fill('559')
```

Here is the iframe:

```
<iframe src="src" class="js-iframe" title="Iframe for security code" allowtransparency="true" referrerpolicy="origin"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

This is the element:

```
<input id="adyen-checkout-encryptedSecurityCode-13535234466" data-fieldtype="encryptedSecurityCode" type="text" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="4" autocomplete="cc-csc" placeholder="3 digits" aria-label="Security code" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="adyen-checkout-encryptedSecurityCode-13535234466-ariaContext" class="js-iframe-input input-field" data-type="gsf" style="display: block;">
```

Any help would be appreciated!

It doesn't fill in, I've noticed that the field only accepts integers, I've tried to fill it integers like this: `number=456 code.fill(str(number))`
When I try to see the trace, 2 errors come up:[image: error]

Comment: Can you try using type instead of fill?

Comment: "This is the element:" sounds like something you should probably get proof of before running `code.fill('559')`: add some code to at least first verify you found the input element? Especially given that fact that you're showing what looks like a 404 for the iframe's source. So in addition to verifying you found what you were trying to find: check whether the iframe even loaded before calling content functions.

Comment: It's difficult to help without the actual site. There could be any manner of arbitrary JS behavior, frames, blocking, etc at play here. Please also share the error as text, not an image, which can't be searched. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I added some verifying, and it finds but doesn't want to click on it or fill it in, the errors are timeouts after 30s.